# DropdownButtonFormField, with fixed width but dynamic text items

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I don't think I understand constraints in Flutter that well so bear with me!

I want to `DropdownButtonFormField` that populates its items from DB. The string could be of any dynamic length. So what I have decided is to have a fixed width `DropdownButtonFormField` and `DropdownMenuItem` will have ellipsed `Text`.

Here is what I have tried.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 136.0,
  child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
    hint: Text("hintText")
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        isDense: true),
    items: [
        DropdownMenuItem<int>(
            value: 0,
            child: TextOneLine(
              "less character",
            ),
        ),
        DropdownMenuItem<int>(
            value: 0,
            child: TextOneLine(
              "mooooorrrrreeee character",
            ),
        )
    ]
  ),
);

class TextOneLine extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  final TextStyle style;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final bool autoSize;

  TextOneLine(
    String data, {
    Key key,
    this.style,
    this.textAlign,
    this.autoSize = false,
  })  : this.data = data,
        assert(data != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
        data,
        style: style,
        textAlign: textAlign,
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      );
  }
}
```

- I am getting overflow error

[image: overflow error]

- but when I click on `DropdownButtonFormField` the list of `DropdownMenuItem` are ellipsed.

[image: drop down list with ellipsed text]

How do I get rid of the Overflow error? I can't have Flexible or Expanded DropDownButtonFormField because the String length could be dynamic (could be longer than what could fit).

Comment: use - `FittedBox` widget - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

Comment: I tried wrapping `FittedBox` around `SizedBox` - the overflow error is not going. I can see the textSize reducing but as I said the error remains

Comment: can you produce minimum reproducible code of the issue ?

Comment: done. check now

Comment: Likely the SizedBox the issue

Comment: most probably, if you change the TextOneLine - maxLines to 2 or 3 you will not get overflow. If you insist to show in 1 line than you should size the text fontSize.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I am using SizedBox to limit the width DropdownButtonFormField. Or else it occupies the full width (which i don't want)

Comment: @Nick changing maxLines to 2 or 3 is not helping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please refer the attached images, I've added 3 images.

Image 1: this is the issue you are getting.

Image 2:  when I removed the `width` from `SizedBox`. Now it shows 3 boxes 1 is hint text and other is empty and 3rd is the drop-down arrow. I think the overflow is causing because of the 2nd empty space.

Image 3: Now in this, I've again added a width to `SizedBox` of `136` and put the `SizedBox` inside a `Container` having a fixed width size of `100` (is the width of the text in dropdown and it will wrap your text as per the width for sure). This resolved the overflow issue as per the code you have given.

I think as you have added a custom widget which is `TextOneLine` causing the issue. There may be some other workarounds but this solved the issue.

```
SizedBox(
        width: 136,
        child: DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
            hint: Text("hintText"),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                isDense: true),
            items: [
              DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                value: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: TextOneLine(
                    "less character",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                  value: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    child: TextOneLine(
                      "mooooorrrrreeee character",
                    ),
                  ))
            ]),
      )
```

[image: image_collage]

Try out this and let me know whether this was the issue (and resolved) and please keep us updated any other workaround you done. Thanks

Comment: that makes sense. it is a very simple solution. i feel dumb now!! Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 45):

I know it might be a bit late to share the answer but I found an easy fix. Just add a `isExpanded: true` to the DropdownButtonFormField.

```
  DropdownButtonFormField<int>(
        hint: Text("hintText"),
        isExpanded: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            isDense: true),
        items: [
          DropdownMenuItem<int>(
            value: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              child: TextOneLine(
                "less character",
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem<int>(
              value: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                child: TextOneLine(
                  "mooooorrrrreeee character",
                ),
              ))
        ])
```

[Before Adding isExpanded property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWwAm.png)
[After Adding isExpanded property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvAti.png)

Comment: really saved me

Comment: not work for me. I used the dd in the `Row`.

Comment: The parent to the row should have wrapped with widget to set a fixed width and the row you are using should have wrapped with Expanded/Flexible widget

Answer (score 0):

that's because you have an item in your list that consist of a too many characters 
like "mooooorrrrreeee character" or something like that